# python draw half-triangle with numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get this output (with comas):

```
1
2, 1
3, 2, 1
4, 3, 2, 1
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

The problem is, i am not able to "remove" the last coma (,) situated next to the number 1 on each line. Here is the code:

```
for i in range(1,6):
for x in range(i,0,-1):
    print("%i,"%(x), end=" ")
print()
```

Comment: look into `','.join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try output last element after `for` loop:

```
for i in range(1,6):
        for x in range(i,1,-1):
            print("%i,"%(x), end=" ")
        print("1", end=" ")
        print()
 #1 
 #2, 1 
 #3, 2, 1 
 #4, 3, 2, 1 
 #5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve it via using [**`str.join`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with [**`range`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and [**`map`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> n = 5
>>> for i in range(n):
...     print(', '.join(map(str, range(i+1, 0, -1))))
...
1
2, 1
3, 2, 1
4, 3, 2, 1
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

If you are looking for one liner solution, then you may write it using nested [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) as:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(', '.join(map(str, range(i+1, 0, -1))) for i in range(n)))
1
2, 1
3, 2, 1
4, 3, 2, 1
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

where `n` is the count of number of lines needed to be printed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is a little bit difficult. I got my answer. Thanks buddy!